# How to increase Auto complete search bar suggestion list items(currently at 8 need to increase up-to 16)

Tags: jquery, laravel, search, autocomplete, bootstrap-typeahead

I have developed a search bar to search items from my products list where more than 10,000 products available. When a user type a word user can see suggestion list with 8 items based on user input. This is my code and code is working perfectly. But what I wants to do is to increase the suggestion list. I have no idea how to that. So if anyone could please help me.

**Nsearch.blade.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h1> test products </h1>
    <input type="text" class="typeahead form-control" name="name">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var path = "{{route('nautocomplete')}}";
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
    source:function(query,process){
        return $.get(path,{query:name},function (data) {
            return process(data);
        })
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**NSearchController.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Shop;
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class NSearchController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        return view('shop.Nsearch');
    }

    public function autocomplete(Request $request){
        $data = Product::select("name")
                ->where("name","LIKE","%{$request->input('name')}%")->get(); 
                return response ()->json($data);
    }
}
```

**web.php (route)**

```
    Route::get ('/nsearch','Shop\NSearchController@index')->name('nsearch');
Route::get ('/nautocomplete', 'Shop\NSearchController@autocomplete')->name('nautocomplete');
```

**Current view**

[image: snap]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's your front-end issue.

### Final Code

```sh
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        items: 20,
        source: function(query,process){
            return $.get(path,{name:query},function (data) {
                return process(data);
            })
        }
    });
```

Read Bootstrap 3 Typeahead documentation in this [link](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead)

### update 1

Have you ever dumped `$data` in your `NSearchController.php` and see the result count?

### update 2

Another thing that you should care:

in you controller you are using `$request->input('name')`, it means you should receive 'name' as a query string; while you are using `$.get(path,{query:name}` and it's wrong. You should change it to `$.get(path,{name:query}`. in your code `$request->input('name')` always return null and SQL query will return all of your products name; then typehead will filter them on your frontend –

### Update 3

just set another value to `items` property. (It's 8 by default)

Comment: thanks for the reply. But adding this dosent increase my suggestion list. I have `dd()` result and it contains more than 10 products.

Comment: @NipunTharuksha another thing that you should care:
in you controller you are using `$request->input('name')`, it means you have have 'name' as a query string. while you are using  `return $.get(path,{query:name},function (data)` and it's wrong. you should refactor it to `return $.get(path,{name:query},function (data)`. in your code `$request->input('name')` always return null and SQL query will return all of your products name then typehead will filter them on your frontend

Comment: @NipunTharuksha I updated my answer. I think you should be ok.

Comment: thanks for this answer. If you could please post a link where I can get more details about this

Comment: @NipunTharuksha No problem buddy. https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead

Comment: could you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57998777/typeahead-dosent-fetch-data-from-the-table-after-adding-some-html-elements