# typeahead doesn't fetch data from the table after adding some html elements

Tags: html, json, laravel, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I'm trying to use auto complete search with `typeahead.js`and this is the code I tried and its working perfectly and output the suggestion list.

**Controller**

```
 public function autocomplete(Request $request){
            $data = Product::select("name")
                    ->where("name","LIKE","%{$request->input('name')}%")->get(); 
                    return response ()->json($data);
        }
```

Now what I need to do is pass some extra elements with that fetched data , something like relevant url of the product via `<a>`. So I have updated my code as below.

**New code in the controller**

```
 public function autocomplete(Request $request){
        $products = Product::
        where("name","LIKE","%{$request->input('name')}%")->get(); 
        $setting = 157.5;
        $data = [];
        foreach ($products as $product){

            $data .= ' <li><a href="'.route('shop.product.listings',['id'=>$product->id,'slug'=>$product->getSlug()]).'"><h1>'.$product->name.'</h1><p>'.number_format(($product->minimum_price)*$setting->value, 2, '.', ',').' LKR</p></a></li>';
        }
                return response ()->json($data);               
    }
```

But when I type a text in the search bar console out put a **error message as a internal error** and it doesn't output anything.

This is the snap of console

[image: snap console]

Could anyone please help me on this. Thanks

**UODATE 01**

When `$data = [];` it generate below error

[image: error01]

[image: snap 02]

When

### I change `$data = [];` to `$data = '';`

in Networks I can see that Network successfully transfer data but no output

[image: success01]

[image: success02]

**Update 03 after modified as [shkory's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4916312/shokry-mohamed)**

[image: after modified]

Comment: click to this link and add error here

Comment: @ShokryMohamed could you please check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not sending data as Html and send as Json. Then generate whatever you wantedm(html) in front end.

Check this one for frontend custom Template:

```
`https://codepen.io/jeremejazz/pen/QyOWmq`
```

Answer (score 1):

return `$data = [];`
and change `$data.` to `$data[]`
in line 87

Comment: sorry but no $data = [] at line87

Comment: change `$data.` to `$data[]` in line 87

Comment: Done and now its showing suggestions but with all html tags. Please refer update02

Comment: what you want now ? you sended html in $data